# JavaScript/jQuery duplicate text highlight won't work in HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file with the code below and I have a problem with it:

```
  <html>
        <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <style type="text/css">
           span.duplicate { background: yellow; }
        </style>

        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

        <script>
            var text = $('p').text(),
                words = text.split(' '),
                sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
                duplicateWords = [],
                sentences = text.split('.'),
                sortedSentences = sentences.slice(0).sort(),
                duplicateSentences = [];


            for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
                if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
                    duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
                }
            }
            duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);

            for (var i=0; i<sortedSentences.length-1; i++) {
                if (sortedSentences[i+1] == sortedSentences[i]) {
                    duplicateSentences.push(sortedSentences[i]);
                }
            }
            duplicateSentences = $.unique(duplicateSentences);

            $('a.words').click(function(){
                var highlighted = $.map(words, function(word){
                    if ($.inArray(word, duplicateWords) > -1)
                        return '<span class="duplicate">' + word + '</span>';
                    else return word;
                });
                $('p').html(highlighted.join(' '));
                return false;
            });

            $('a.sentences').click(function(){
                var highlighted = $.map(sentences, function(sentence){
                    if ($.inArray(sentence, duplicateSentences) > -1)
                        return '<span class="duplicate">' + sentence + '</span>';
                    else return sentence;
                });
                $('p').html(highlighted.join('.'));
                return false;
            });
        </script>

    </head>

        <body>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </p>
            <hr />
            <a class="words" href="#">Find duplicate words</a>
            |
            <a class="sentences" href="#">Find duplicate sentences</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It should work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SaQAs/1/ but not working in my browser.

What did I do?

- Paste code from jsfiddle into HTML my file (with CSS, javascript and
  put them between HTML tags)
- add link to jQuery library

When I call file from localhost (I'm using XAMMP) it displays correctly but when I click on link for highlight duplicates, nothing happens :(

Console in developer tools (Chrome) shows nothing (no errors, no info - just blank).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put your script at the end of the `<body>` tag or (as in the JSFiddle) in an `OnDomReady` event, and it should work.

Comment: If @Scott's right, and I believe he is, the problem is the order of execution of your script on the page.  You have to imagine when you see $(..), it's actually fetching the item from the page and if it runs before the page is completed, it finds nothing and therefore does nothing (jQuery performs no operation if no items are found).

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use jQuery's `$( document ).ready(function() {/*execute your code*/});` in this situation.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers :) Scott was right, i was put script at the end of '<body>' tag and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the script before the DOM is ready, enter your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded`/`load` event, or jquery within `$('document').ready()` and some other events, so that it executes after the page has been loaded, for example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // code here
});

document.onload = function() {
    // code here
}

//or in Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Or simply add the scripts after the body (because the html is read from the top, the script will run after the body), for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your content here -->
    </body>

    <script>
        // all your script here, after the body has loaded
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) I use second solution and it works. I think it's enough for so simple code like mine.

Answer (score 0):

I need to say taht im positively supprised how quick i get feedback.

Thanks for helping me solve my first problem. I put scripts at the end of `<body>` tak and it works :)

But i have another problem (i dont know i will have it until i paste my own content beetwen `<p>`).

I need little modify script for my need and i dont know how.

My content looks like this:

```
<p>

Folder listing with files making "pairs":

My File.id 10.zip // file package
My File.id 10.html / file package description
My File.id 11.zip
My File.id 11.html

---

Index.txt of files "pairs" in folder(one line menas 2 files in folder - html and zip) every line have break `\r\n`:

My File.id 10
My File.id 11

</p>
```

and so on... In folder will be something about ~200 files (html+zip) and in index will be ~100 records.

What i need?

I need to hilight every "pair" that contains name of  zip and html file and their record in index (record can't contain extensions).

For now i can't do that because files in folder have extensions .html and .zip and records in index don't have any and script can't recognize duplicate correctly (i can't hide extension in html or php because i need se them).

What im trying to achieve?

I need to know visually that is there some "alone" record in index or some alone files in forlder not indexed in index, and i imagine when i press "hilight duplicates" then every file thah have "pair" will be hilighted and alone files or records i index will be white so i can find it quickly

For now i modified script to recognize sentences by new line `(\n)` but i dont know what next. Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
<style type="text/css">
span.duplicate { background: yellow; }
</style>

</head>


<body>

<p>

My File.id 10.zip
My File.id 10.html
My File.id 11.zip
My File.id 11.html

---

My File.id 10
My File.id 11

</p>

<hr />
<a class="words" href="#">Find duplicate words</a>
|
<a class="sentences" href="#">Find duplicate sentences</a>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
var text = $('p').text(),
    words = text.split('\n'),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = [],
    sentences = text.split('\n'),
    sortedSentences = sentences.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateSentences = [];


for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
        duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
}
duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);

for (var i=0; i<sortedSentences.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedSentences[i+1] == sortedSentences[i]) {
        duplicateSentences.push(sortedSentences[i]);
    }
}
duplicateSentences = $.unique(duplicateSentences);

$('a.words').click(function(){
    var highlighted = $.map(words, function(word){
        if ($.inArray(word, duplicateWords) > -1)
            return '<span class="duplicate">' + word + '</span>';
        else return word;
    });
    $('p').html(highlighted.join('<br/>'));
    return false;
});

$('a.sentences').click(function(){
    var highlighted = $.map(sentences, function(sentence){
        if ($.inArray(sentence, duplicateSentences) > -1)
            return '<span class="duplicate">' + sentence + '</span>';
        else return sentence;
    });
    $('p').html(highlighted.join('<br/>'));
    return false;
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```